# Calling multiple java methods from xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

My xsl looks like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:baseclass="xalan://com.company.BaseClass"
            version="2.0">

<!-- code here -->
<xsl:variable name="destination"><xsl:value-of select="baseclass:getObjByName($objName):getDestination($variable)"/></xsl:variable>
<!-- more code -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All methods are static. question: is it possible to call two java methods from xsl - one from base class and another from result?

Comment: What processor? Saxon, Xalan, QuiXSLT, or inside the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this class:

```
package my.pack;
public class Foo{
  public int bar(){
    return 4;
  }
}
```

You need a XSLT like this:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="java:my.pack.Foo.bar()"/>
```

So you generate a

```
4
```

Regards.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. but in my case bar() will return object rather then primitive. and I want to call that returned object
<xsl:value-of select="java:my.pack.Foo.bar().bar1()"/>
is that possible?

Comment: I cant imagine why this should not be possible. I never tried that because its dirty.